# change default load path for devise views and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems, load-path

This is my gem file `gem 'devise', '1.5.2'`
and this is my routes.rb `devise_for :users`
*This is what i learnt:*
**Initially** the controller,views were loading from `vender/gems/1.91/ruby/devise 1.5.2`
so what i did i added modified the app structure to app/controllers/devise/(and copied all controller from `vender/gems/1.91/ruby/devise 1.5.2/app/controllers`) as well as did the same to views because everytime the views were loading from vendor so i when i added devise folder ,it was loading from `app/views/users/` instead of vendor.
BUT just now i did bundle install and everything is again the same and loading from vendor...i didnt understand why bundle install change this.
so what changes do i need to do so that next time my changes doesnt get lost.
**all i want is to load **devise views/controllers*** from **myapp/app/controllers and myapp/app/views*rather than from vendor/bundle/gems/1.91/ruby/gems/devise 1.5.2** where i load the gems for my app.pls advise??**
Did bundle install changed everyting???how to prevent this in future??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all [Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Don't copy manually, use the generator

```
rails generate devise:views
```

All needed views will be generated under app/views/devise

As for the controllers, create them under `app/controllers`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

end
```

or

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

end
```

and change `routes.rb` to point them:

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "<YOUR_SESSION_CONTROLLER>", :registrations =>  "<YOUR_REGISTRATION_CONTROLLER>"}
```

Comment: thanks @Raichel....i got worked...hope now when i do bundle install...it wont change my setup...